# How to send Facebook users back to their respective Profile pages?

Tags: facebook, profile

I have Facebook users logged into my site. After they are on my site, I want to return each user back to their own individual Profiles.

Specifically, I want to return them to the Profile page that shows their Tabs. e.g.
http://www.facebook.com/home.php?#!/username

Rather than sending them back to their default (home) page.

What link can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just send them to `http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=<UID>` url.

Comment: Thanks! Ok. So this gets me close, but it still takes them to the Home page of their Profile. Is there some way to send them straight to the *Profile page* of their Profile (i.e. where they see the tabs called Wall, Info, Photos etc?)

Comment: @dave this would send them to that page. There are two pages - home and profile. Home is `http://www.facebook.com/home.php` profile is that one.